# Installed Cassandra on Windows 11, getting IllegalAccessError: "Cannot initialize un-mmaper"

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to install Cassandra on a Windows machine, with Java 1.8.
The Error message I am getting is the following:

```
ERROR [main] 2023-01-27 09:45:26,820 FileUtils.java:80 - Cannot initialize un-mmaper.  (Are you using a non-Oracle JVM?)  Compacted data files will not be removed promptly.  Consider using an Oracle JVM or using standard disk access mode
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils (in unnamed module @0x6aa8e115) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x6aa8e115
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.guessFileStore(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1093)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySimpleConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:493)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:324)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:153)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:137)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:680)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:622)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
INFO  [main] 2023-01-27 09:45:26,944 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2023-01-27 09:45:26,945 DatabaseDescriptor.java:781 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
Exception (java.lang.IllegalAccessError) encountered during startup: superclass access check failed: class org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$JmxRegistry (in unnamed module @0x6aa8e115) cannot access class sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl (in module java.rmi) because module java.rmi does not export sun.rmi.registry to unnamed module @0x6aa8e115
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$JmxRegistry (in unnamed module @0x6aa8e115) cannot access class sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl (in module java.rmi) because module java.rmi does not export sun.rmi.registry to unnamed module @0x6aa8e115
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:204)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:633)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
ERROR [main] 2023-01-27 09:45:27,067 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$JmxRegistry (in unnamed module @0x6aa8e115) cannot access class sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl (in module java.rmi) because module java.rmi does not export sun.rmi.registry to unnamed module @0x6aa8e115
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:204)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:633)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
```

after which it exists with the message: Main Completed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Cassandra 4 by chance? not supported on windows.

Comment: no ? 
So what to do, I am just newbie and want to learn Cassandra on my Windows machine. Start with Cassandra 3 ?

Comment: Use docker containers

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Compatibility

The multiple `IllegalAccessError` messages indicate to me that you are running an unsupported version of Java that is not compatible with Cassandra.

You stated that you are running Java 8 but there's a chance that you have a newer version installed on your machine and `JAVA_HOME` is pointing at the newer version.

#### Java support

Cassandra 3.0/3.11 and earlier versions only supports Java 8. Cassandra 4.0 added support for Java 11 LTS ([CASSANDRA-9608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608)) so C* 4.x will work with either Java 8 or Java 11.

Provided that you have a supported version of Java installed, I've seen issues with some flavours of Java which do not seem to be compatible with Cassandra. My recommendation is to install a TCK-certified flavour of Java such as Oracle JVM or OpenJDK.

#### Windows support

For what it's worth, the Java file I/O library that Cassandra uses has always been problematic on Windows particularly with NTFS. It has been a constant source of issues for users that we decided it wasn't good for the project to continue support (see the [discussion in this thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/cpbpx74ysrs7xwgklpx2wh6003jms260)).

We eventually dropped Windows support completely in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

#### Alternatives

The recommended workarounds for Windows users are:

- Deploy [Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster with open-source [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) has a free tier where you can launch a cluster in just 5 clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!